# Magento redirect multiple language url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

We're facing a duplicate content problem with our magento url's
We are having two languages
domain.ro (base language) and en.domain.ro

The problem is if we have in main language the url below:
domain.ro/my-url.html

if we access this in en subdomain it points to the same page
en.domain.ro/my-url.html  --> this should point to en.domain.ro/my-url-en.html

Comment: You should use href-lang meta tag in header to resolve duplicate content issue. And you can change url by changing url key in that store.

Comment: Thanks, but hreflang doesn;t help me, i'm already using it and show me the same version of the link since is not redirected. Yes i've changed the url in backend but is indexed by google and i want to redirect the to english version. Problem was that i using the en version with the same name in my base language and was  making a big duplicate until i've change the url's in english for EN version, it's there a way so i can redirect the 301 manually?